# Pandas to_sql avoid duplicate rows

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am using pandas' `to_sql` method to insert data into a mysql table. The mysql table already exists and I'd like to avoid inserting duplicate rows.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Is there a way to do this in python?

```
# mysql connection
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
user = 'user1'
pwd = 'xxxx'
host =  'aa1.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com'
port = 3306
database = 'main'

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}".format(user,pwd,host,database))


con = engine.connect()
df.to_sql(name="dfx", con=con, if_exists = 'append')
con.close()
```

Are there any work-arounds, if there isn't a straight forward way to do this?

Comment: If your table isn't exceptionally large you could simply read the whole DB into a df and do a concat with a drop duplicates into your existing code from you post

Comment: I'd say skip the Pandas layer and go for raw SQL so you can pass the duplicate handling to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do an "upsert" (insert or update). [Pangres](https://github.com/ThibTrip/pangres/wiki/Upsert) is a useful package that will allow you to do an upsert using a pandas df. If you don't want to update the row if it exists, that is also an option by setting `if_row_exists` to `'ignore'`

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of 'upsert' before today, but it sounds interesting. You could certainly delete dupes after the data is loaded into your table.

```
WITH a as
(
SELECT Firstname,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by Firstname, empID ORDER BY Firstname) 
AS duplicateRecCount
FROM dbo.tblEmployee
)
--Now Delete Duplicate Records
DELETE FROM a
WHERE duplicateRecCount > 1
```

That will work fine, unless you have billions of rows.